# The Lefschetz hyperplane theorem and when there is an even number of vanishing cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let's suppose we have a smooth, complex algebraic surface $S \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ where $N$ is some large positive integer. Then, a generic Lefschetz pencil is a family of hyperplanes $H_t$ and we may obtain hyperplane sections $C_t=S \cap H_t$. The Lefschetz hyperplane theorem says that all 1-cycles of $S$ are homologous to a 1-cycle in some generic $C_t$. Put another way, if $i:C \hookrightarrow S$ is the inclusion map, the $i_*:H_1(C,\mathbb{Z}) \to H_1(S,\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective.

Let's now do things over $\mathbb{C}$ so that we may use Hodge theory to conclude that $\dim H_1(S,\mathbb{C})$ and $\dim H_1(C, \mathbb{C})$ are both even. Hence, $\ker i_*$ is even dimensional as well. This kernel is generated by the vanishing cycles in the Lefschetz fibration and hence, there are an even number of them. This same argument works also for $\dim_\mathbb{C} = 2k$, not just surfaces. In that case, the vanishing cycles live in $H_{2k-1}$ and there is an even number of them.

In this argument, I appealed to the Hodge symmetry. My question is:

> Without appealing to Hodge theory, why are there an even number of vanishing cycles? Is there a geometric argument for the parity of $\dim \ker i_*$ that uses some facts about Kähler manifolds without Hodge theory?

Comment: The number of vanishing cycles on a Lefschetz pencil equals to the degree of the dual variety of $S$. They are not linearly independent in $H_1(S,\mathbb C)$ in general.

Comment: But perhaps here is something related to what you are looking for: Alan Landman has a theorem which claims that if $X$ is smooth projective and $\dim(X)$ is odd, then the degree of the dual variety of $X$ is even. So in particular, the number of vanishing cycles in a Lefschetz pencil of such $X$ is even.

Comment: @AGlearner Is it true that the number of vanishing cycles is at least the dimension of the kernel of $i_*$? Or are there elements of this kernel that don't come from vanishing cycles?

Comment: Yes, since the set of vanishing cycles in a Lefschetz pencil generate $\ker(i_*)$, the number of such vanishing cycles is at least the dimension of $\ker(i_*)$.

Comment: There was a typo in my first comment: Vanishing cycles are typically not linearly independent in $H_1(C,\mathbb C)$ (The homology on the hyperplane section).

Comment: @AGlearner Are vanishing cycles in 1-1 correspondence with critical points of the Lefschetz fibration? It seems the degree of the dual variety of $X$ is computed by counting the number of hyperplanes that all pass through a given point and are also tangent to $X$. Tangency somehow corresponds to critical points.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @AGlearner Ah, I was thinking it's possible to have one vanishing cycle that has two Lefschetz thimbles going to distinct critical points (a more geometric view). So then, on the face of it, it looks like vanishing cycles are not in 1-1 correspondence with critical points. But the proper way to think about this is algebraically: there are two vanishing cycles; they just happen to be linearly dependent in homology.

Comment: If one deform a vanishing cycle $\alpha$ associated to a critical point $p$ in a Lefschetz pencil to another critical point $q$ along a path $l$, then it is not true that $l_*\alpha$ "vanishes" at $q$ in general. (A topological obstruction could be the intersection number between $l_*\alpha$ and the vanishing cycle $\beta$ at $q$ by Picard-Lefschetz formula.) So there is no well-defined Lefschetz thimble over $\alpha$ going to critical point distinct form $p$.

Comment: For $\mathbb P^2$ embedded in $\mathbb P^n$ by the degree $d$ Veronese embedding, I think you get an odd number of critical points if and only if $d$ is even.